# How to delete specific files older than 1hour on cronjob?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I'm using cronjob for Ubuntu 20.04. I want to auto delete files older than 1hour and only files with filename begins with master-stdout.log*

How can I do this?

```
find /root/logs/ * -mmin +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: What does not work with the command given? and why do you have * in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the files whose name starts with `master-stdout.log` and that have not been modified in the last hour, recursively under `/root/logs/`:

```
LC_ALL=C find /root/logs/ -name 'master-stdout.log*' -mmin +59 -delete
```

Here using the `-mmin` and `-delete` extensions of GNU `find`, as found on Ubuntu and other GNU-based systems.

Note that `-mmin +60` would select the files whose age in minutes rounded up to the next integer is *strictly* greater than 60. So would not select the files whose age is in-between 60 and 61 minutes.

That deletes all files regardless of their type, though note that it won't delete files of type *directory* if they're not empty. Also note that removing a file from a directory does update the last modification time of that directory, and `-delete` implies `-depth` meaning that files are processed *before* the directory where they're found in. So if an old file is removed from a directory, that directory won't be removed even if it was over an hour old at the time `find` was started.

Also note that for files of type *symlink*, it's the age of the symlink itself, not that of the target of the symlink that is being considered.

To delete only *regular* files (and exclude all other types of files including fifos, sockets, directories, symlinks...), add `-type f` before `-delete`. Or `! -type d` to consider all types of files except *directories*.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case because it's not likely that anything other than files would have that name but for future reference, `-type f` may also needed to specify that they are files. For example, if the name were to begin `sssd` or if there were an application that writes to `/var/log/` and the directory and files start with the same pattern.

Comment: @NasirRiley, I've added a few notes about handling of different file types.

Comment: Cool. Your answer is good but it's always good to be clear.